# How to keep files created during a Google Cloud Build when it fails?

Tags: google-cloud-build

I would like to retrieve output of builds (such as screenshots from cypress) when a build fails.
My first idea was to upload those file on a bucket with `gsutil`. However, when the build fails, it doesn't execute the next step so I can't upload files.

I also tried with `gcsfuse`  but couldn't get around it.

Has someone found a way to do that?

Comment: Is there a bash shell that is connected to the interface?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [remote-builder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/remote-builder) custom builder. It creates a Compute Engine VM in your project and execute the build step on that VM instead of the Google-managed instance.

The default configuration for this custom builder deletes the instance whenever it [catches an EXIT signal](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/blob/baaf1ef667fc1d7a1b1441824be7f3fabab14b4a/remote-builder/run-builder.sh#L33) but you could either:

- comment that line so that the instance isn't deleted. In case of build step failure, you could go to your Cloud Console > Compute Engine VMs and ssh into the instance and copy the screenshots files wherever you want. You'll need to remember to delete the instance though (even when the build step is successful)
- or customize the [cleanup()](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/blob/baaf1ef667fc1d7a1b1441824be7f3fabab14b4a/remote-builder/run-builder.sh#L4) function to have it copy the files elsewhere before it delete the VM.